# Sails.js - data object becomes blank when I was exec()

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, sails.js

My app's controller action has a while loop (while (item = stream.read()) )

wherein if I do the following:

```
while (item = stream.read()) {        
    console.log(item);
     }
```

I can see the item object although if I do the following:

```
while (item = stream.read()) { 
    Buzzfeed.find({'title': {'contains': item.title}}).exec(function(err, item) {
        console.log(item); 
    });
}
```

the data comes out as a series of empty arrays

For reference, here's the link to my entire controller: http://pastebin.com/YQJTC9w0

Curious where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are `Buzzfeed` records in your database whose titles contain the `item.title` values that are being returned?  If not, those empty arrays may be the expected output; you'd be doing multiple queries that return no results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
while (item = stream.read()) { 
  Buzzfeed
   .find()
   .where({'title': {'contains': item.title}})
   .exec(function(err, item) {
      console.log(item); 
    });
}
```

From `Waterline ORM`'s [documentation](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/waterline/models), `find` is used to find a single criteria. It should use `where` instead because it need a query "where" logic.

Comment: Even if the code is right, its good to include some explanation.

Comment: Sorry for that, thank you for your advice. Actually because my english is bad, I feel hard to explain even just a simple thing, lol. Won't repeat in future.

Comment: The OP's syntax is fine; the first argument to `find` is the where clause.  Chaining `.where()` is an optional alternative syntax.  So, your code is functionally equivalent to what they posted.

Comment: @sgress454 I also don't know it's bug or not. Because I also have an issue like that if chaining some field with `where` inside `find`, don't quite understand but it works with that way so I always use that way.